# How to use Tensorflow's `file_io` in multi-project/multi-configuration setting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I'm part of multiple GCP organizations and projects. When I run `gcloud config configurations list` I get:

```
NAME        IS_ACTIVE   ACCOUNT          PROJECT
default     False       knub@org_1.com   org1
project_b   True        knub@org_2.com   org2
```

Now I'm trying to run

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

file_io.file_exists("gs://bucket_from_project_b/test.txt")
```

but I get the error

```
knub@org_1.com does not have storage.objects.get access to
gs://bucket_from_project_b/test.txt`
```

This happens even though the active project is `project_b`. Everything else, like `gcloud` and `gsutil`, work and respect the currently active configuration.

*How do I make `file_io` respect my active configuration?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `file_io` uses the application credentials in `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` and not the active configuration in `~/.config/gcloud/active_config`.
Furthermore, `application_default_credentials.json` is not updated when one switches between projects (via `gcloud config configurations activate default`), but has to be updated manually each time again by calling `gcloud auth application-default login` after switching.